# Как передать в CustomEditor Enum, который находится в классе? (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Перед классом MonoBehaviour есть публичный класс, в котором содержится переменная enum. В MyScript : MonoBehaviour есть переменная типа TestClass. Как передать эту переменную в CustomEditor?

```
[System.Serializable]
public class testClass {
    public enum testEnum
    {
    e1,
    e2,
    e3,
    };

    public testEnum TestEnum;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class RandomScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public testClass TestClass;

/////
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(RandomScript))]
public class RandomScript_Editor : Editor {
    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        RandomScript rs = (RandomScript) target;
        rs.TestClass.TestEnum = EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Test Enum", rs.TestClass.TestEnum);
    }
}
```

Если делать через FindProperty, то получаю ошибку:
`'SerializedProperty' does not contain a definition for 'TestEnum1' and no accessible extension method 'TestEnum1' accepting a first argument of type 'SerializedProperty' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Если через EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup, то ошибка такая:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Enum' to 'testClass.TestEnum1'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`, причём почему-то берётся имя enum, а не инициализированной им переменной.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно передать enum?

Comment: Для начала нужно привести код, а не эти "для примера"

Comment: Обновил пост, добавил ссылку на код

Comment: На будущее: в вопросе нужно приводить **код**, а не **ссылку на код**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы всё правильно делаете) просто не совсем поняли ошибку. `EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup` в качестве результата возвращает тип `System.Enum`, а не тот, который вы передали.

Вот ошибка вам и говорит, что вы пытаетесь назначить 'System.Enum' в поле, которое ожидает 'testClass.TestEnum1'. 'System.Enum' не является наследником 'testClass.TestEnum1' - значит неявно приведение невозможно. После чего вам говорят, что, возможно, вы забыли сделать явное приведение типов. Другими словами ваша строка должна выглядеть вот так:

```
rs.TestClass.TestEnum = (testClass.testEnum)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Test Enum", rs.TestClass.TestEnum);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сам не догадался. Точнее, требовалось `(testClass.testEnum)`.

Comment: @АлексейПетродий, ну, я из ошибки взял название енама)